# Angularjs ng-if compare the day inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, date, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have a loop in a table that displays the date and I need to show a different td, depending on whether the day(not the time) is different.

What I need is something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat='session in sessions'>
<td ng-if="session.start.DAY != session.end.DAY">
{{::session.start | date:'d MMM H:mm'}} 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
{{::session.end | date:'d MMM H:mm'}}</td> 
</td>

<td ng-if="session.start.DAY == session.end.DAY">
{{::session.start | date:'H:mm'}} 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
{{::session.end | date:'H:mm - d/MMM'}}
</td>
</tr>
```

The date is in this format: 2015-09-29T14:18:43 and I want to compare only this part 2015-09-29

I know the code above doesn't work, but what could be done in this case?

Comment: When using ng-if you will be preventing the td from being emitted, which may or may not be what you want however in most cases you have a set number of columns and you can use ng-show to hide or not hide the column.  This keeps the html consistent.  As far as the actual expressions, I don't see why they wouldn't work provided you have objects named session in the controller.

Comment: Not much known about the data being compared. Dates are not trivial. Concept seems like it should work...show data samples that produce unexpected results

Comment: How to compare everything but the time? Given that you have this data coming  2015-09-29T14:18:43 and I want to compare only this  2015-09-29

Answer (score 0):

Just check Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/LS9US1RUzmoE133WUpND?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="testctrl">

    <div ng-repeat='session in sessions'>


      <div ng-show="session.startDAY | limitTo: 10 == session.endDAY | limitTo: 10 ">

          {{session.startDAY | date:'d MMM H:mm' }}

      </div>

       <div ng-show="session.startDAY != session.endDAY">

          {{session.startDAY }}

      </div>

    </div>

    </div>
```

Thank you,
Chaitanya

Comment: mate, I editted my question now, I guess it wasnt clear. The date is in this format: 2015-09-29T14:18:43 and I want to compare only this part 2015-09-29

Comment: CNandamuri, did you see that even if you change the operator from == to !=  this will make ng-show receive a truthy value and thus display the date? 
 <div ng-show="session.startDAY | limitTo: 10 != session.endDAY | limitTo: 10 ">